# crop the central part of image to fit the container of fixed height

Tags: css

I need to center crop the image without stretching the image to fit the container. I did it like below. It crops the bottom height only to fit the container when image height is larger but when it is of less height it doesn't fit the container. How can I center crop the image and fit to the container of giver size?

```
 <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img class="full-width" src="../images/123.jpg" />                                               </div>

css:
.imagecontainer {
background: #dbdbdb;
max-height: 166px;
min-height: 166px;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
}

.full-width {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you put code in jsfillde

Comment: here is the jsfillde of my code. http://jsfiddle.net/bv26D/. I need   the central part filling the width and height of the container without stretching and re-sizing the image.

Answer (score 0):

try this `<img class="full-width" src="../images/123.jpg" height=166 width=100%/>`

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/msqEB/1/)**

HTML

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <div class="full-width"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imagecontainer {
    background: #dbdbdb;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.full-width {
    max-height: 166px;
    min-height: 166px;
    background: url("http://www.codess.net/wp-content/uploads/hello_world.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

retain the `<img src="">` thing and the opacity trick

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/M6BTR/168/)**</kbd>

```
.imagecontainer {
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 166px;
    background-image: url('http://www.codess.net/wp-content/uploads/hello_world.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imagecontainer .full-width {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: It works when I provide background: url but not through img src and I need to pass image source through php .. not finding a way to resolve it .